# White borders after resume

Tags: nvidia, suspend

Upon resuming my machine, the background image turns white, and all of the windows have thick white borders around them.

This started happening after I "played" with my Nvidia drivers by upgading to the latest version. Tried to change/downgrade driver versions, reinstalling unity, but without luck so far...

Using a Dell 7559 with the Nvidia proprietary driver (nouveau just does not work well for me...), ubuntu 16.10 and latest kernel 4.10.1

Here is an depicting this situation:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Yes I too have this issue using Nvidia 375.39 ... same issue using 378.13 ... nouveau clears up this issue yet cannot handle newer graphics demands like Vulkan

Comment: FYI same as https://askubuntu.com/questions/887933/weird-pixelated-white-border-ubuntu-xenial-16-04

Comment: @Pilot6 should be the one you mention is duplicate from this? as this was earlier than the one you mention. 27 feb < 2 mar .

Comment: It does not matter which is earlier. The other one has an answer.