# Weird pixelated white border. Ubuntu Xenial (16.04)

Tags: drivers, unity, nvidia, graphics

Out of the blue I started getting these weird borders around my windows. It either happens after coming back from full-screen applications, or after system resume. A reboot fixes this problem, but only temporarily. I have not updated my graphics drivers (not manually, automatically maybe) or had any problems since installing last year.

My video card is a NVIDIA Quadro K1000M, and I've been using NVIDIA binary driver version 375.39 since launch. I have not yet tried tinkering with the drivers, seeing if it would fix the problem or not.

[image: image of white borders]

Comment: I have the exact same problem, and the weird borders are even wider on my computer. This indeed appeared after a system update which installed the 378 drivers but kept the 375 in use. So I tried with the 378 without luck. My kernel is 4.8.17-040817-generic and my card a 960M. Any help will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: here's a [gist for the relevant packages update](https://gist.github.com/ddidier/c7a7cddca4bd87e11846d5d5cff2101b), or I hope so. @a-stroh : can you try to find common updates in your `/var/log/apt/history.log` ?

Answer (score 8):

The culprit is the new version of the NVidia driver. Reverting to 375 doesn't work because IMHO it has also been updated (minor version) and/or its dependencies are a mix of several versions. Anyway:

1. Remove the PPA. On my computer I deleted the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list` pointing to the repository `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu xenial main`
2. Remove all the installed NVidia packages, i.e. `nvidia-*`. On my computer I deleted several packages with `apt remove nvidia-361 nvidia-375 nvidia-378`
3. Update the packages list with `apt update`
4. Install the last official version (i.e. 367) with `apt install nvidia-367`

As a side note, I'm always amazed how updates regularly break Ubuntu...

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue for me. Same feelings here regarding the updates. Despite this clearly being nVidia's fault, at this stage I am considering not touching anything other than the major security updates with a ten foot pole and only upgrading via LTS releases where everything is thoroughly tested together.

Comment: I sadly must use an unofficial kernel (mainline PPA)  to support my laptop :-( Please consider validating my answer

Comment: Completely out of scope, but quoting Linus Torvalds seems appropriate: "Nvidia, Fuck You". Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYWzMvlj2RQ. Should have bought a different laptop... Thanks for the answer, it helped but gave me different problems with modal windows on top of others.

Answer (score 5):

Its' not a solution per se, but it helps to get the white borders removed.

We just need to restart the Unity, by using the following command -

`unity --replace`,

which will restart the Desktop Manager, but will keep are current Session intact.

So no logout/login needed, just call the above command whenever these NVIDIA drivers create your screen unusable.

> EDIT-
>
> Have tried this solution only on Ubuntu, so I guess most of the Debian Distro's will work here, but not sure about any other Linux Distro.

---

### UPDATE

Above Solution was a temporary one... As it is true that latest drivers of NVIDIA breaks Ubuntu... I guess u should try the solution in the following link - [Strange artifacts along window borders](https://askubuntu.com/a/896544/549143)

As nvidia-367 updates itself automatically to nvidia-375, we need to get a stable nvidia-370, which doesn't update itself. This solved my issue, but I am still not convinced, as I still get screen tearing when watching a high-res video...

Answer (score 1):

Updating the Nvidia driver to 384.69 solved the issue for me.

In "Software and Updates" open "Additional drivers" tab an there should be "nvidia-384" option available. Select->Apply Changes->Restart

If not then visit:
  http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html