# Strange coloured border appearing around windows

Tags: 16.04, graphics, display

Recently, I have noticed that on most applications I have on Ubuntu 16.04, when I load the application, the window is displayed with a strange multi-coloured border (see the images below). If I maximise the window though, the border disappears and the window is displayed as expected.

This started happening for no apparent reason. If I reboot my machine, things return to normal at first, but after a while the problem comes back.

The issue occurs on most applications, including Nautilus, Software Centre, Terminal, System Settings, etc... I also get the same border appearing when I right click on the desktop, with the border surrounding the pop-up menu.

However, I have noticed that it does not happen on Chrome, but it does happen on other applications which did not come with Ubuntu by default.

Any ideas on what is causing the problem? Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your themes is corrupted, google chrome uses its own theme, unless you go into advanced settings in chromes settings and changes its default behavior!    Try changing your theme!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried changing the theme in System Settings -> Appearance, but this did not help. There are three themes available (Ambiance, Radiance, High Contrast), but they all result in this same problem...

Comment: What graphics card do you have, and, if  nvidia, are you using the proprietary drivers ? What laptop model ? Could be a hardware failure.

Comment: Same issue here. Happens consistently after coming back from Suspend mode. Using nVidia binary driver v378.13. Seems to have started recently after installing proposed updates pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the latest nVidia drivers (v378). Even if you have been using v375 before, it seems that the same issue was backported into some of it's minor versions. Try rolling back to v367, as described in this  [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/889101/452837) (notice that you need to disable the repo, otherwise 375 gets installed when calling sudo apt-get install nvidia-367)