# Grainy background around dialog box

Tags: compiz

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it was working fine. There was not any issue with the display. But today morning when I turned on the laptop from sleep, it has started to display a white grainy background around the dialog boxes and the corner buttons (close, minimise, and maximise buttons) are not visible. I can see some sort of change in the grain pattern in the position of the buttons when I place the mouse over the buttons. The buttons are working though.

[image]

The display around it is fine, as you can see.

Comment: Looks like some kind of bug. What graphics card is there? If you want to check, run `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 VGA `, just don't dump the output into a comment.

Comment: And http://askubuntu.com/questions/889166/strange-coloured-border-appearing-around-windows and http://askubuntu.com/questions/896764/dizzy-background-around-popup-windows . That second link seems to include a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is present in 375 and 378 drivers...

Given that simply killing compiz process fixes the bad border problem, I have tested a solution that works on my Ubuntu 16.04 system every time after the system wakes.

#### Step 1:

I created a script called `fixbadborders` in the directory `/lib/systemd/system-sleep`.
It contained the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
## This file (or a link to it) must be in the folder /lib/systemd/system-sleep/
## Purpose: Kill compiz after system wakes up from sleep.
## This will fix bad window borders caused by Nvidia driver 375.39.
kill $(ps -C compiz -o pid=)
```

#### Step 2:

Allowed the script to have execute permission with:

```
sudo chmod +x fixbadborders
```

To remove this script:

```
sudo rm /lib/systemd/system-sleep/fixbadborders
```

All credits go to [Sun Bear](https://askubuntu.com/users/541417/sun-bear) who created this script [comment 13](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-375/+bug/1667158/comments/13)